# Easiest way to copy entities and associations between databases?

Tags: c#, copy, associations, entity

I really need someone to shed some light in the dark. What is the easiest way of copying entities and their assocations between databases? The Schemas are exactly the same.

We have the following situation:

```
Standard 1 -> * StandardDomain 1 -> * StandardSubDomain 1 -> * StandardControl
```

I need to be able to copy a standard record with all its related entities and copy it to another database.

Is there some kind of library avaible for this type of operations?

**Solved**

I solved this by loading the entities with linq to sql and map them with AutoMapper to my domain objects. Once my domain is saved, NHibernate will take care of saving it's associations by enabling Cascade.All

Please help me out!

Comment: add some more info to your question... you can do it in so many different ways...

Comment: I found the solution for my problem. I will update my question. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by loading the entities with linq to sql and map them with AutoMapper to my domain objects. Once my domain is saved, NHibernate will take care of saving it's associations by enabling Cascade.All